# Where to find chromedriver.log in selenium using c#. Where can i see the log file of chromedriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, logging, selenium-chromedriver

Where to find chromedriver.log in selenium using c#. Where can i see the log file of chromedriver?

```
ChromeOptions optn= new ChromeOptions();
optn.AddArgument("--verbose");
optn.AddArgument("--log-path=D:\\chromedriver.log");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Driver\",optn);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aWh0U7WHEJGAuASTuYHIAQ");
```

I'm using the above code but unable to see the log file in specified location. Please help me to find it

Comment: Have you checked in your project path?

Answer (score 21):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
var optn = new ChromeOptions();
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"D:\Driver\"); 
service.LogPath = "chromedriver.log";
service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, optn);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aWh0U7WHEJGAuASTuYHIAQ");
```

The ChromeOptions is for the browser process itself. Logging goes to the ChromeDriver by setting the ChromeDriverService variables.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that it works if you remove the "--" from your arguments. The library code must be adding them. So your code should look like this..

```
ChromeOptions optn= new ChromeOptions();
optn.AddArgument("verbose");
optn.AddArgument("log-path=D:\\chromedriver.log");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Driver\",optn);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aWh0U7WHEJGAuASTuYHIAQ");
```

Comment: `optn.AddArgument(...)` passes the argument to Chrome.exe. `verbose` and `log-path` are ChromeDriver.exe arguments.

Comment: @naavis: So this solution can never work, can it? Definitely **does not work** for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most easy solution will be -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "D:\\chromedriver.log");
```

Comment: This is for Java, not C#